# How to correct horizontal flip function to prevent it from altering images' colors

Tags: c++, c, ruby

stb_image.h provides a method to flip an image vertically and it works fine. I tried to implement an horizontal flip aka mirror but it alters the image colors.

On pictures that only have 3 colors you could get bluish or reddish or even magenta colored pictures instead of their actual colors. It's the same if we're talking about JPEG or PNG images, you get the same strange results. Curiously if you flip that very same image vertically, its colors look normal.

I've tried testing pretty much any function you could find here and the code I'm providing you with has been the only one that got me close to my actual goal.

````
// Function I've been trying to implement to enable Horizontal Flip
static void stbi_horizontal_flip(void *image, int w, int h, int bytes_per_pixel)
{
    size_t line_bytes = (size_t)w * bytes_per_pixel;
    stbi_uc temp[line_bytes];
    stbi_uc *bytes = (stbi_uc *)image;
    Debug() << line_bytes;
    for (int col = 0; col < h; col++) {
        stbi_uc *line = bytes + col * line_bytes;
        memcpy(&temp, line, line_bytes);
        for (int row = 0; row < line_bytes; row++) {
            line[row] = temp[line_bytes - row - bytes_per_pixel];
        }
    }
    stbi_horizontally_flip_on_load = false;
}
// stb_image's function for Vertical Flip
static void stbi__vertical_flip(void *image, int w, int h, int bytes_per_pixel)
{
    int row;
    size_t bytes_per_row = (size_t)w * bytes_per_pixel;
    stbi_uc temp[2048];
    stbi_uc *bytes = (stbi_uc *)image;
    for (row = 0; row < (h>>1); row++) {
        stbi_uc *row0 = bytes + row * bytes_per_row;
        stbi_uc *row1 = bytes + (h - row - 1) * bytes_per_row;
        size_t bytes_left = bytes_per_row;
        while (bytes_left) {
            size_t bytes_copy = (bytes_left < sizeof(temp)) ? bytes_left : sizeof(temp);
            memcpy(temp, row0, bytes_copy);
            memcpy(row0, row1, bytes_copy);
            memcpy(row1, temp, bytes_copy);
            row0 += bytes_copy;
            row1 += bytes_copy;
            bytes_left -= bytes_copy;
        }
    }
}

static unsigned char *stbi__load_and_postprocess_8bit(stbi__context *s, int *x, int *y, int *comp, int req_comp)
{
    stbi__result_info ri;
    void *result = stbi__load_main(s, x, y, comp, req_comp, &ri, 8);
    if (result == NULL) return NULL;
    if (ri.bits_per_channel != 8) {
        STBI_ASSERT(ri.bits_per_channel == 16);
        result = stbi__convert_16_to_8((stbi__uint16 *) result, *x, *y, req_comp == 0 ? *comp : req_comp);
        ri.bits_per_channel = 8;
    }
    // @TODO: move stbi__convert_format to here
    if (stbi_horizontally_flip_on_load) {
        int channels = req_comp ? req_comp : *comp;
        stbi_horizontal_flip(result, *x, *y, channels * sizeof(stbi_uc));
    }
    if (stbi__vertically_flip_on_load) {
        int channels = req_comp ? req_comp : *comp;
        stbi__vertical_flip(result, *x, *y, channels * sizeof(stbi_uc));
    }
    return (unsigned char *) result;
}

STBIDEF stbi_uc *stbi_load_from_file(FILE *f, int *x, int *y, int *comp, int req_comp)
{
    unsigned char *result;
    stbi__context s;
    stbi__start_file(&s,f);
    result = stbi__load_and_postprocess_8bit(&s,x,y,comp,req_comp);
    if (result) {
        // need to 'unget' all the characters in the IO buffer
        fseek(f, - (int) (s.img_buffer_end - s.img_buffer), SEEK_CUR);
    }
    return result;
}

STBIDEF stbi_uc *stbi_load(char const *filename, int *x, int *y, int *comp, int req_comp)
{
    FILE *f = stbi__fopen(filename, "rb");
    unsigned char *result;
    if (!f) return stbi__errpuc("can't fopen", "Unable to open file");
        result = stbi_load_from_file(f,x,y,comp,req_comp);
    fclose(f);
    return result;
}

STBIDEF stbi_uc *stbi_load_from_callbacks(stbi_io_callbacks const *clbk, void *user, int *x, int *y, int *comp, int req_comp)
{
    stbi__context s;
    stbi__start_callbacks(&s, (stbi_io_callbacks *) clbk, user);
    return stbi__load_and_postprocess_8bit(&s,x,y,comp,req_comp);
}

void Gosu::load_image_file(Gosu::Bitmap& bitmap, const string& filename)
{
    Buffer buffer;
    load_file(buffer, filename);
    load_image_file(bitmap, buffer.front_reader());
}

void Gosu::load_image_file(Gosu::Bitmap& bitmap, Reader input)
{
    bool needs_color_key = is_bmp(input);
    stbi_io_callbacks callbacks;
    callbacks.read = read_callback;
    callbacks.skip = skip_callback;
    callbacks.eof = eof_callback;
    int x, y, n;
    stbi_uc* bytes = stbi_load_from_callbacks(&callbacks, &input, &x, &y, &n, STBI_rgb_alpha);
    if (bytes == nullptr) {
        throw runtime_error("Cannot load image: " + string(stbi_failure_reason()));
    }
    bitmap.resize(x, y);
    printf("Channels %d, Gosu Color size %d, unsigned char size %d, bytes array size %d",
         n, sizeof(Gosu::Color), sizeof(stbi_uc), sizeof(bytes));
    // Output: Channels 3 or 4, Gosu Color size 4, unsigned char size 1,       bytes array 8
    memcpy(bitmap.data(), bytes, x * y * sizeof(Gosu::Color));
    stbi_image_free(bytes);
    if (needs_color_key) apply_color_key(bitmap, Gosu::Color::FUCHSIA);
}```


// Output: Channels 3 or 4, Gosu Color size 4, unsigned char size 1, bytes array 8

That is what I got back from stb_image, but I'd prefer to get an 8bit array instead. Even so what actually matters is to get rid of that unexpected color change.
````

Comment: You are flipping individual bytes, rather than whole pixels. You need to swap groups of `bytes_per_pixel` adjacent bytes. For example, imagine the image is just one pixel wide. Flip should do nothing. But your code changes each row from, say, `{R,G,B}` to `{B,G,R}`, thus altering the color of each pixel.

Comment: By the way I think it was mean to downvote my question. I've been dealing with this issue for a couple of days trying several variants. If making mistakes is forbidden for any human being, then sites like stackoverflow wouldn't even be online by now.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to Igor's comment** I could focus on my immediate problem and not long after I came up with the code I've posted below.

What I've been wondering since I finally could flip the images horizontally was why the other methods I found either on the web or as part of image processors' code didn't work as expected. O_o? Sometimes I copied and pasted them only changing some variables' names or types to match stb_image's and they still failed either to compile or display a decent result.

By the way, I tried before to subtract positions to the right value to no avail but it made me think some of them could be used as nice color blend effects. XD

````
// Horizontal Flip by Kyonides Arkanthes shared under GPLv2 or v3
static void stbi_kyon_horizontal_flip(void *image, int w, int h, int bytes_per_pixel)
{
  size_t line_bytes = (size_t)w * bytes_per_pixel;
  stbi_uc temp[line_bytes];
  stbi_uc *bytes = (stbi_uc *)image;
  int lpos, rpos;
  for (int col = 0; col < h; col++) {
    stbi_uc *line = bytes + col * line_bytes;
    memcpy(&temp, line, line_bytes);
    for (int row = 0; row < w; row++) {
      lpos = row * bytes_per_pixel;
      rpos = line_bytes - row * bytes_per_pixel - 1;
      line[lpos] = temp[rpos - 3];
      line[lpos + 1] = temp[rpos - 2];
      line[lpos + 2] = temp[rpos - 1];
      line[lpos + 3] = temp[rpos];
    }
  }
  stbi_kyon_horizontally_flip_on_load = false;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You just reversed the order of RGBA, you try to use this, I tested, the effect is normal.

```
            for (int row = 0; row < Qimg2.width(); row++) {
                lpos = row * bytes_per_pixel;
                rpos = line_bytes - row * bytes_per_pixel - 1;
                line[lpos] = temp[rpos - 2];
                line[lpos + 1] = temp[rpos - 1];
                line[lpos + 2] = temp[rpos - 3];
                line[lpos + 3] = temp[rpos];
            }
```